# Cannot connect to remote sql database with an error 26

Tags: sql-server, networking, sql-server-2005

I have a small application that uses a SQL-Server express 2005 database located on a remote machine. This has worked for years. I've not only been able to access it via the application, but also on the development machine. The other day I came in to the server (windows 7 machine) shut down from a power outage. Since then I have not been able to access the database and receive an error 26. I have checked the firewall and it does indeed have the exception for sqlbrowser and UDP 1434 set. I also checked Configuration Manager and SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) and SQL Server Browser are both running. (Even did a restart on both)

Client Protocols are enabled for Shared Memory, TCP/IP and Named Pipes.

Here is where it gets strange (At least for me). Both the development machine and the machine that uses the application that works with the database were both set to Obtain IP Address. If I set these to a static address they are then able to access the database without issues. I would like to not have to set static IP's and get things running the way they have for the past couple of years. Does this shed any light on what I might need to check to see why I can no longer access this server without a static IP on the remote machines?

The server is 2007 pro along with the development machine. The remote machine that uses the application is Windows 10 pro.

I should also state that I can browse the network and access normal shares via windows network with and without the static ip from both machines.

EDIT: The exact message I get when I don't use a static ip is:

***A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server)***

I get this error even when trying to connect using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the error message? Error 26 is pretty useless without a description. There is no error 26 in sql server.

Comment: @SeanLange, I have updated the topic to include the error I'm receiving.

Answer (score 0):

After many installations I learned that opening the SQL Server port in the firewall works always when using the *default* instance, but with named instances and SQL Browser opening the ports some times doesn't prevent the firewall for blocking connections, specially in small environments that doesn't have a proper server like the one you describe (I think that it's related to the dynamic port feature that SQL Server use by default with named instances, but I'm not sure).

When I have to use named instances instead of opening the ports I create rules for the programs themselves and it has worked fine until now. Create two rules using `New rule` > `Programs` > `This program path`, one for:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqlbrowser.exe`

and other for:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe` (maybe this location is a bit different when using the `SQLEXPRESS` instance).

I usually create the rules only for private network locations, but maybe you should create the rules for all locations just to be sure (and if this works, try unchecking public locations from the rules).

For future installations note that you can configure Express editions to use the default instance `MSSQLSERVER` at install time (and *only* at install time), with that option you just open port 1433 and you are done.